# Не добавляются записи с дублирующими именами

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, index

Есть такой код:

```
if (isset($_POST['add_product'])) {
    $req_fields = array('product-title','product-categorie','product-quantity','buying-price', 'saleing-price');
    validate_fields($req_fields);

    if (empty($errors)) {
        $p_name  = clean($db->escape($_POST['product-title']));
        $p_cat   = clean($db->escape($_POST['product-categorie']));
        $p_qty   = clean($db->escape($_POST['product-quantity']));   
        $p_buy   = clean($db->escape($_POST['buying-price']));
        $total   = $p_qty*$p_buy ;
        $p_sale  = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['saleing-price']));

        if (is_null($_POST['product-photo']) || $_POST['product-photo'] === "") {
            $media_id = '0';
        } else {
            $media_id = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['product-photo']));
        }

        $date    = make_date();
        $query  = "INSERT INTO products (";
        $query .=" name,quantity,buy_price,total,sale_price,categorie_id,media_id,date";
        $query .=") VALUES (";
        $query .=" '{$p_name}', '{$p_qty}', '{$p_buy}', '{$total}', '{$p_sale}', '{$p_cat}', '{$media_id}', '{$date}'";
        $query .=")";
        $query .=" ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name='{$p_name}'";
        if ($db->query($query)) {
            $session->msg('s',"Готовый продукт добавлен в базу ");
            redirect('add_product.php', false);
        } else {
            $session->msg('d',' Ошибка  что то пошло не так!');
            redirect('product.php', false);
        }
     } else {
         $session->msg("d", $errors);
         redirect('add_product.php',false);
     }
}
```

Видно, что код берет данные формы и, "очищая" их, вставляет в таблицу `products`. Всё бы ничего, но когда дублируются названия товаров из поля p_name, он не добавляет данные в таблицу, хотя и пишет что "Готовый продукт добавлен в базу". Например, в базе есть товар "Хлеб", добавленный вчера. Если сегодня ещё раз добавить товар с название "Хлеб", то пишет "Готовый продукт добавлен в базу", но ничего не добавляет. Чувствую, что во всем виновата строка `$query .=" ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name='{$p_name}'";` но если его убрать то скрипт не срабатывает( . Подскажите, что делать дорогие друзья, спасибо заранее.

Comment: Что значит "скрипт не срабатывает"? И покажите, пожалуйста, структуру БД.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конструкция [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) срабатывает для колонок с [UNIQUE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/constraint-primary-key.html) индексом.

В случае возникновения ошибки запускается код, описанный в выражении `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` и обновляет найденную строку по указанному правилу.

```
$query .=" ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name='{$p_name}'";
```

В вашем случае видно, что в найденной записи данная колонка просто будет обновляться на новое значение (а т.к. оно совпадает с предыдущим, то вы просто не заметите результат). Если убрать эту конструкцию, то MySQL просто вернёт ошибку, сообщая о том, что уже есть запись с таким значением для колонки name.

Суть `UNIQUE` индекса в том, чтобы не допустить дублирования полей, когда это действительно важно (например, если нам нужно иметь уникальный username в таблице пользователей). Если для вашей системы допустимо использование одинаковых записей в колонке name, просто удалите индекс.

```
ALTER TABLE my_table DROP INDEX index_name
```

Название индекса вам нужно самому посмотреть в структуре таблицы.

Comment: Спасибо Hast, сделал так и всё заработал